# Use Analytics + Tag Manager to track link clicks of specific URLs

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, click-tracking

For a PDF brochure that is accessed through a banner link, how would one track the clicks on that banner using Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager?

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.zoomowl.com/link-click-tracking-using-googleanalytics/), and [this one](https://measureschool.com/track-outbound-link-clicks/).

Because a PDF isn't a page that people land on, nor is it outbound, I need to do this a little differently than in the tutorials (which focus on tracking outbound link clicks).

I'm a noob with Tag Manager, so please include details, and don't hesitate to explain the obvious. Thanks.

Comment: The banner is on your site as opposed to advertising running on other sites?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, it's a banner linking to a PDF brochure on the same site. It's not outbound to some other site. (I didn't come up with the idea of doing it this way, nor did I author the PDF.) And if there's a better way to track clicks for this case than Analytics + TM, I'm open to other approaches too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a tag in GTM that sends your event to GA.
2. Go to Variables. Click Configure for built-in vars.
3. Select the Clicked Element like so:
   [image]
4. Make a Click All Elements trigger.
5. In the trigger config, Do something like this ( a[href*=".pdf"] ):
   [image]
6. Now use the trigger for your tag.

It should work now.
In addition, you can use CJS variables or other built-in variables or their combo to enrich your category, action and label there.